# Regarding custom variables during gtm setting (submit form form)

Tags: java, function, if-statement, variables

I'm a marketer, not a developer, so I have a shallow knowledge towards the development team, so I'd like to ask you a question here. Please help me a lot.

[Image Form Submission Value corresponding to Number 1 html Note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM8Ei.png)

1. All four areas of the Form Submission Form are set to be triggered only when you click the send button.

In the existing landing page, the trigger operated normally enough with the following custom variables.

2. As in the attached sequence picture, I answered all four forms in the existing landing page through JavaScript custom variables and used them normally so that they could only work by pressing the send button.
3. However, this time, after creating a new landing page, the query value is required* Three things must be entered in the same way so that the trigger does not work even though I set the same Java custom variable so that it can be submitted.
   *Required values are *.

[New landing page html hangout plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmtKn.png)

▼If function of random variable set▼ Among those variables, the document.querySelector does not seem to work on the new page, but I have no idea which variable to use.

4. In addition, even if we solve it up to three times, one of the required values on this newly renewed landing page is not a simple blank, but a drop-down value, so we are at a loss because we don't know what variables to set the value when we enter it.

It can be a bit long, but if you know how to solve it, I would really appreciate it if you could answer at least one thing.